# Forge viewer: Auto-start animation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We would like to trigger/auto-start an animation/simulation of a specific object (Revit `ElementID`) when the model loads in the Forge viewer. The goal would be to move a cube (Revit `ElementID`) back and forth on the floor in a repeating loop. Would this be possible using any relevant extension or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but there is no built-in extension you can use out of the box. The animation logic has to be a custom implementation.

From a given ElementId/UniqueId you need to find the corresponding dbId, see [that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720285/4916074) for a starting point on how to do that.

From a given dbId, you can obtain fragmentIds and use those to apply transforms to the components in the viewer. The animation logic has to be by your own application. You can refer to that article [How to create animations in the viewer?](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/04/how-to-create-animations-in-the-viewer.html) or one of the several demos I wrote performing animations:

[Kinematics](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598957eed77eb159a67998ed) - [source](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Kinematics)

[Physics](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5959fa67f8b8e4b500e7ec35) - [source](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Physics.RigidBody)

You can use the **Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT** and **Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT** to trigger the animation logic, so you can make sure the model is fully loaded. See also that article: [Asynchronous viewer events notification](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/asynchronous-viewer-events-notification.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. This will be very helpful towards our goals.