# Autodesk ObjectId and ElementId in dwg

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am use to develop one web app using Forge API. It's working well and good. At the same time am using design automation in forge. I can able to create Package and it's working fine.

I will process the dwg file using forge api preparing to viewer. I can able to view dwg in browser.

My issue is I have viewer click event the event click populate the element id. However, my package I can get only the object id. element id and object id totally different.

What is the conman id each object client and server side.

Summary: when user click the object in viewer I want to capture id and store my local database. and using package I need to process the user clicked object.

Example: when user click the drawing number in viewer. From the next time I want change the drawing number dynamically using call package from C# code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Moderators - Please would you remove the hold on this question. In the context of the autodesk* tags used here, the question is perfectly understandable. (The only inappropriate tag is the generic 'forge' tag, as the question is about 'autodesk-forge', but that mistake is understandable). Thanks.

Comment: @StephenPreston happened to come across this while reviewing. Your comment makes it clear that it should be re-opened (and so it has)

Answer (score 2):

For an RVT file, one easy way to handle this is to extract the Forge `externalId` from the Forge object properties. That is equal to the Revit element `UniqueId` property. The [RvtMetaProp Revit add-in](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/use-forge-or-spreadsheet-to-create-shared-parameters.html) makes use of this.

Oh, now I just found a better, more complete and succinct explanation of [Unique IDs for Forge Viewer Elements](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/08/revit-versus-forge-ids-and-add-in-installation.html#4):

The Viewer gives access to three types of IDs when dealing with Revit files:

- `dbId`: this is viewer specific and used to manipulate elements within the viewer, such as for the `.getProperties()` method.
- Revit `ElementID`: exposed as part of the `Name` property in the viewer. When you select something, the Property panel title is in the form of 'Name [12345]'. You can parse this name string and extract the element id.
- Revit `UniqueID`: exposed as the `externalId` property in the `.getProperty()` response.

Comment: This operation abuot DWG file  am not using RVT .  I Upload the DWG file using Forge API and translate to SVF for preparing viewer and i can able to view in browser now.  What is the conman id each object client and server side for DWG

Comment: Please take a look at this example: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer.
The common ID that is understood on the server and the client is called a "handle".

Comment: Elaborating on Albert's response - an ObjectId in AutoCAD is unique to a session and is not persisted. The unique identifier within a DWG file is the object handle. In addition to the sample that Albert quotes, please review this blog post - https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/entity-handle-from-dwg-file-in-viewer.html.